# Universal-Size doesn't fit in Itunes Connect

Tags: ios, size, app-store-connect, universal

I've sucessfully uploaded my new App into ItunesConnect, unfortunately only the "universal"-App size doesn't fit to Apple... is that something I have to worry about? or can I ignore it....
What could be the solution?

Thank you verry much for your help!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNJeg.png)

Comment: Can you share screenshot where are you seeing this error?

Comment: of course! I've pasted it in my question.

Comment: where are you getting this error? On Which Screen?

Comment: Its an error that comes from the Itunes Connect Site not from the Compiler... Don't know if that is something I have to worry about....